# sql: expected 1 arguments, got 2

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, go

I am trying to execute queries here, but doesn't seem to work with always a sql: expected 1 arguments, got 2 error

```
    return func(c echo.Context) error {
        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        defer rows.Close()

        result := PostCollection{}

        for rows.Next() {
            post := Post{}
            err2 := rows.Scan(&post.ID, &post.Fullname, &post.Content)
            if err2 != nil {
                panic(err2)
            }

            result.Posts = append(result.Posts, post)
        }

        return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, result)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the DB schema of the table `posts`? Does it just have the 3 columns & in order: `ID, Fullname, Content`?

Comment: @badman the error is not coming from the code you've shown, it is coming from some other db code. You need to show the code that actually causes the error, otherwise it will be difficult to provide a definite answer.

Comment: @badman the error refers to a mismatched number of parameter placeholders in the sql query string and the number of actual parameters passed to the query-executing function. For example, you can get that error if you have something like: `db.Query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=?", 123, 456)`, you can see that there is only one `?` placeholder, but two arguments `123` and `456`. This kind of code would produce the error message you quoted.

Answer (score 1):

if your just want query ID, FullName, Content
cloud try this

```
db.Query("SELECT ID, FullName, Content FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC")
```